# Bootstrap register modal not working properly

Tags: php, jquery, sql, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I hope some of u could help me with my problem.

I'm trying to get my bootstrap modal working, but it seems, it won't do the things I want. I set up my modal like this:

```
<div id="Sign-Up">
<div class="control-group">

<form name="myForm" role="form" action="register.php" method ="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">

              <label class="control-label" for="Email">Email:</label>
              <div class="controls">
  <input id="Email" name="Email" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="TestUser@testsite.com" class="input-large" required="">
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="userid">Alias:</label>
              <div class="controls">
               <input id="userid" name="userid" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="TestUser" class="input-large" required=>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Password input-->
            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="password1">Passwort:</label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input id="password1" name="password1" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="********" class="input-large" required=>
                <em>1-8 Zeichen</em>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="password2">Passwort wiederholen:</label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input id="password2" class="form-control" name="password2" type="password" placeholder="********" class="input-large" required>
              </form>
              </div>
```

I added a "register.php" for the database insertion:

```
<?php
    require('connection.php');
    // If the values are posted, insert them into the database.
    if (isset($_POST['userid']) && isset($_POST['password1'])){
        $username = $_POST['userid'];
        $email = $_POST['Email'];
        $password1 = $_POST['password1'];
        $password2 = $_POST ['password2'];

        if ($password1 == $password2) {
    echo "Password is OK";

} else  {
    echo "You entered two different passwords";
}

        $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (userid, password1, Email) VALUES ('$username', '$password1', '$email')";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if($result){
            $msg = "User Created Successfully.";
        }
    }
?>
```

And finally the database connection "connection.php":

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST','localhost');
define('DB_NAME','users');
define('DB_USER','****');
define('DB_PASSWORD','****');

$conn=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$conn) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
if (mysqli_connect_errno($conn))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
else
{
echo "Successfully connected to your database…";
}
?>
```

If I check the "register.php" inside my browser, I can see that I got a valid database connection. My problem at this point is, that I can't figure out how to submit the data into my database. If I press my register button, the modal just refreshes to my startscreen without any data insertion.

Would be nice, if anyone could check out my code and knows whats the problem there.

Greetings anz

PS: That's the button I coded:

```
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="confirmsignup"></label>
      <div class="controls">
        <button id="confirmsignup" name="confirmsignup" type="submit" formmethod="post" class="btn btn-success" value="Anmelden">Anmelden</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

---

Edit:

That's my fully coded modal now, which still doesn't seem to work:

```
<!-- Login -->

<div class="modal fade bs-modal-sm" id="myLogin" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <br>
    <div class="bs-example bs-example-tabs">
      <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#signin" data-toggle="tab">Anmelden</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#signup" data-toggle="tab">Registrieren</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#why" data-toggle="tab">Why?</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="why">
      <p>We need this information so that you can receive access to the site and its content. Rest assured your information will not be sold, traded, or given to anyone.</p>
      <p></p>
      <br>
      Please contact <a mailto:href="..."></a>...</a> for any other inquiries.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="signin">
      <form class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
          <!-- Sign In Form --> 
          <!-- Text input-->
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="userid">Alias:</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input required="" id="userid" name="userid" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="TestUser" class="input-medium" required="">
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Password input-->
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="passwordinput">Passwort:</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input required="" id="passwordinput" name="passwordinput" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="********" class="input-medium">
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Multiple Checkboxes (inline) -->
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="rememberme"></label>
            <div class="controls">
              <label class="checkbox inline" for="rememberme-0">
                <input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" id="rememberme-0" value="Remember me">
                Eingeloggt bleiben </label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Button -->
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="signin"></label>
            <div class="controls">
              <button id="signin" name="signin" class="btn btn-success">Anmelden</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="signup">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
    <!-- Sign Up Form -->
    <div id="Sign-Up">
    <div class="control-group">
    <form name="myForm" role="form" action="register.php" method ="post" >
      <label class="control-label" for="Email">Email:</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input id="Email" name="Email" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="TestUser@test.com" class="input-large" required="">
      </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Text input-->
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="userid">Alias:</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input id="userid" name="userid" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="TestUser" class="input-large" required=>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Password input-->
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="password1">Passwort:</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input id="password1" name="password1" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="********" class="input-large" required=>
          <em>1-8 Zeichen</em> </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Text input-->
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="password2">Passwort wiederholen:</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input id="password2" class="form-control" name="password2" type="password" placeholder="********" class="input-large" required>
        </div>
      </div>

      </div>

      <!-- Button -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Send!" id="submit">
      </div>
      </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is in your javascript finction validateForm() or if there is no such function then remove this onsubmit="return validateForm()" and where is button in html code

Comment: Looks like I don't have a javascript function "validateForm()". I removed the line "onsubmit="return validateForm()"", but it's still not working.

Comment: where is register button in your html code if there  is not one then add into form <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button>

Comment: I edited my main post. Check out the bottom code frame for my button. That's the code i use actually for the register button, which doesn't work.

Comment: Is the button inside form tags <form>   button  </form>

Comment: Actually yes, it is.

Comment: look at this example   http://untame.net/2013/05/how-to-build-a-modal-contact-form-in-twitter-bootstrap-with-php-ajax/

Comment: I looked at your example and re-coded my submit button like this:     `<div class="modal-footer">
    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Send!" id="submit">
    </div>` and it's still not working.

Comment: move this belowe form open tag <div class="control-group">  and check if all div tags are opened and closed inside form.

Comment: I tried this and it still doesn't work .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1

/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
</style>
</head>
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myLogin">Modal form</button>
<!-- Login -->

<div class="modal fade bs-modal-sm" id="myLogin" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <br>
    <div class="bs-example bs-example-tabs">
      <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#signin" data-toggle="tab">Anmelden</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#signup" data-toggle="tab">Registrieren</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#why" data-toggle="tab">Why?</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="why">
      <p>We need this information so that you can receive access to the site and its content. Rest assured your information will not be sold, traded, or given to anyone.</p>
      <p></p>
      <br>
      Please contact <a mailto:href="..."></a>...</a> for any other inquiries.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="signin">
        <fieldset>  
          <form class="form-horizontal" action="signin.php" method="POST">

          <!-- Sign In Form --> 
          <!-- Text input-->
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="userid">Alias:</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input required="" id="userid" name="userid" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="TestUser" class="input-medium" required="">
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Password input-->
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="passwordinput">Passwort:</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input required="" id="passwordinput" name="passwordinput" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="********" class="input-medium">
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Multiple Checkboxes (inline) -->
          <div class="control-group">
            <input type="checkbox" class="control-label" name="rememberme" id="rememberme-0" value="Remember me">
            <label class="control-label" for="rememberme-0">Eingeloggt bleiben </label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Button -->
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="signin"></label>
            <div class="controls">
              <button id="signin" name="signin" class="btn btn-success">Anmelden</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          </form>
        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="signup">

    <fieldset>
    <!-- Sign Up Form -->
    <div id="Sign-Up">

        <form name="myForm" role="form" action="register.php" method ="post" >
        <div class="control-group">  
          <label class="control-label" for="Email">Email:</label>
          <div class="controls">
           <input id="Email" name="Email" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="TestUser@test.com" class="input-large" required="">
          </div>
        </div>

      <!-- Text input-->
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="userid">Alias:</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input id="userid" name="userid" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="TestUser" class="input-large" required=>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Password input-->
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="password1">Passwort:</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input id="password1" name="password1" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="********" class="input-large" required=>
          <em>1-8 Zeichen</em> </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Text input-->
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="password2">Passwort wiederholen:</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input id="password2" class="form-control" name="password2" type="password" placeholder="********" class="input-large" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Button -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Send" id="submit">
      </div>
      </form>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```